# How to enlarge a video element when clicked on it?

Tags: html, angular, video-streaming, html5-video

I have multiples video elements streaming webcam of various users. When i click on a specific video element it should open a video modal showing the stream of that particular user. I have tried giving the id of that particular stream to the modal, but there can be only one id in a single html page. Please help me as i am new to this.

**multiple video elements**

```
<div *ngFor="let el of videoElements; let i = index" class=" embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 col-xs-6">
      <video class="img-responsive embed-responsive-item mt-md" id='{{el.id}}'
        [attr.muted]="i == 0 ? 'muted' : null" style="border: 2px solid #e3e3e3;"
        (click)="enlargeVideo(el.id)"></video>
</div>
```

**the modal**

```
<div id="enlargeVideoModal" class="modal" data-easein="flipYIn" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
aria-labelledby="costumModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <video class="img-responsive embed-responsive-item mt-md" id={{largeVideoId}}
    style="border: 2px solid #e3e3e3;"></video>
</div>
```

**function for opening the modal**

```
enlargeVideo = (id: any) => {
    $('div.popup-messages').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
    });
    this.largeVideoId = id;
    $('#'+id).remove();
    $('#' + id).removeAttr('id');
    $('#enlargeVideoModal').modal({
        show: 'true'
    });
    if (this.IsEnlargeVideo === false) {
        this.IsEnlargeVideo = true;
    } else {
        this.IsEnlargeVideo = false;
      }
   }
```

Comment: where is the source tag for your video tag ?

Comment: @Shahbaaz there is no source tag. It depends on the id. Every user has different id. It will render the stream depending on the id. So i have to use id only